# WooCommerce advanced payment calculate error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found some code in the stackoverflow. The codes can be used to calculate the advance payment on the admin edit order page. The code works well. But  This error message display -  "A non-numeric value encountered in ...". when the advance payment field is empty .

Can anyone give a solution please ..?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'calculate_advance_payment', 10, 1);
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_discount', 'vp_add_sub_total', 10, 1);
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'save_order_custom_field_meta_data', 12, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'editable_order_custom_field' );

// Output a custom editable field in backend edit order pages under general section
function editable_order_custom_field( $order ){            

// Get "Delivery Type" from meta data (not item meta data)
$updated_advance_payment = $order->get_meta('_advance_payment');

// Replace "Delivery Type" value by the meta data if it exist
$advancePayment = $updated_advance_payment ? $updated_advance_payment : ( isset($item_value) ? $item_value : '');

// Display the custom editable field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array(
        'id'            => 'advance_payment',
        'label'         => __("Advance Payment:", "woocommerce"),
        'value'         => $advancePayment,
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
    )
   );
}

// Save the custom editable field value as order meta data and update order item meta data
function save_order_custom_field_meta_data( $post_id, $post ){
if( isset( $_POST[ 'advance_payment' ] )){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_advance_payment', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'advance_payment' ] ) );

    // Update the existing item meta data
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'item_id_ref' ] ) ){
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $_POST[ 'item_id_ref' ], 'Advance Payment', $_POST[ 'advance_payment' ] );
    }
}
}

function calculate_advance_payment( $the_order ) {
$getTotal = $the_order->get_total();
$updateTotal = $getTotal - get_post_meta($the_order->get_id(), "_advance_payment", true);
$the_order->set_total($updateTotal);
$the_order->save();
}

function vp_add_sub_total( $the_order ) {
global $post, $the_order; ?>
<tr>
<td class="label">Advance Payment:</td>
<td width="1%"></td>
<td class="total"><?php echo wc_price(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_advance_payment", true));?></td>
</tr><?php
}
```

This line in particular shows the problem -

```
$updateTotal = $getTotal - get_post_meta($the_order->get_id(), "_advance_payment", true);
```

[image]

[image]

[Post original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344353/woocommerce-admin-custom-order-total-calculate/67367043#67367043)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually answered this question in the original post. It's due to numeric values are in strings. I was getting a same issue with this code. When adding to numeric values that are in strings it should be called with `float` or `(int)`. Below is my solution to the issue and it also prevents the function from adding the values multiple times. Including "`if( get_post_meta( $order_id, 'advance_payment', true ) ) return; // Exit if already processed`" will prevent `calculate_advance_payment()` function from running each time the page is loaded & adding multiple entries.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'calculate_advance_payment', 10, 1);
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_discount', 'vp_add_sub_total', 10, 1);
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'save_order_custom_field_meta_data', 12, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'editable_order_custom_field' );

// Output a custom editable field in backend edit order pages under general section
function editable_order_custom_field( $order ){            
    
    // Get "Delivery Type" from meta data (not item meta data)
    $updated_advance_payment = $order->get_meta('advance_payment');

    // Replace "Delivery Type" value by the meta data if it exist
    $advanced_payment = $updated_advance_payment ? $updated_advance_payment : ( isset($item_value) ? $item_value : '');

    // Display the custom editable field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array(
            'id'            => 'advance_payment',
            'label'         => __("Advance Payment:", "woocommerce"),
            'value'         => $advanced_payment,
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        )
    );
}

// Save the custom editable field value as order meta data and update order item meta data  
function save_order_custom_field_meta_data( $post_id, $post ){
    //global $order;
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'advance_payment' ] )){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'advance_payment', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'advance_payment' ] ) );
        
        // Update the existing item meta data
        if( isset( $_POST[ 'item_id_ref' ] ) ){
            wc_update_order_item_meta( $_POST[ 'item_id_ref' ], 'Advance Payment', $_POST[ 'advance_payment' ] );
        }
    }
}

function calculate_advance_payment( $order ) {
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $getTotal = $order->get_total();
    $advanced_payment = get_post_meta($order_id, 'advance_payment', true);
    $order_total = (float)$getTotal - (float)$advanced_payment;
    $order->set_total( $order_total );
    // Checking if this has already been done avoiding reload
    if( get_post_meta( $order_id, 'advance_payment', true ) ) 
       return; // Exit if already processed
    $order->save();
    
}

function vp_add_sub_total( $order ) {
    global $post, $order; 
?>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Advance Payment:</td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td class="total"><?php echo wc_price(get_post_meta($post->ID, "advance_payment", true));?></td>
    </tr><?php
}
```

[My reply to original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344353/how-to-calculate-custom-order-total-in-woocommerce-edit-order/67367043#67367043)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was busy. So sorry for the late replay. Your answer is accepted. Thanks again.