# Recalculate Completed Orders Tax on WooCommerce to subtract Tax from order Total

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

here is a situation I'm facing, I appreciate any help I can get on this:

So here is the situation, I have a WordPress store integrated with WooCommerce.

Setup:

product price include tax.
Germanized for WooCommerce plugin

Situation: WooCommerce Tax feature was disabled for a while, but there were orders that were made, as result the tax wasn't calculated. Now that orders are marked as completed, I would like to edit orders and recalculate orders including Tax.

I've been able to edit orders either by adding a custom Filter in functions.php

```
    add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'make_order_editable', 9999, 2 );
     
    function make_order_editable( $allow_edit, $order ) {
        if ( $order->get_status() === 'completed' ) {
            $allow_edit = true;
        }
        return $allow_edit;
    }
```

Otherwise change order status to pending payment so I can recalculate the order.

Well, when recalculate the orders, Tax is being added to the total of order, this is the default behavior of woocommerce.

PROBLEM TO FIX: I would like the recalculation to subtract Tax from the order total amount.

I've tried multiple custom codes on the functions.php nothing worked I will list them bellow:

```
function custom_recalculate_order_total($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['calculate-action'])) {
        // Get the order ID
        $order_id = isset($_POST['post_ID']) ? intval($_POST['post_ID']) : 0;

        if ($order_id > 0) {
            // Get the order
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            $order_total = $order->get_total();
            $tax = $order->get_total_tax();
            $new_total = $order_total - $tax;
            $order->set_total($new_total);
            $order->save();
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_save_order_items', 'custom_recalculate_order_total', 10, 1);
```

```
function custom_adjust_tax_on_recalculate($taxes, $cart) {
    if (isset($_POST['calculate-action'])) {
        // Get the order subtotal before tax
        $subtotal = $cart->cart_contents_total;
        $tax_rate = 0.10;
        $tax_amount = $subtotal * $tax_rate;
        $taxes = array(
            'tax_total' => $tax_amount,
        );
    }
    return $taxes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_taxes', 'custom_adjust_tax_on_recalculate', 10, 2);
```

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_before_calculate_taxes", "custom_order_before_calculate_taxes", 10, 2);
function custom_order_before_calculate_taxes($order, $args) {
    if (isset($_POST['calculate-action'])) {
        $subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();
        $tax_rate = 0.10;
        $tax_amount = $subtotal * $tax_rate;
        $order->set_total_tax($tax_amount);
    }
}
```

Feel free to request any extra information you might need.

some related question I've checked: WooCommerce: Adding tax to old (completed) orders Woocommerce recalculating tax on completed orders ignores that VAT is included in product WooCommerce add order admin hook for recalculate button

Comment: all hooks that you tested have nothing to do with editing orders. Use this hook woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta or save_post_shop_order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate Custom order total in WooCommerce edit order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344353/how-to-calculate-custom-order-total-in-woocommerce-edit-order)